# Animation for a GridView

Tags: android, gridview, android-animation

Anybody knwos, how I can animate my GridView after deleting 1 entry? I want something like this:

[image: GridView]

The first is my normal gridview with 8 items. If I'm deleting one item, I want, that a animate starts and the coloumn of the deleted item will slide up and fill the free place.
Anybody an idea?
Thanks for help :)

Comment: Have you implemented this gridview successfully? If yes can you share some code which can be helpful to others in development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of possible ways to achieve that can be the following set of steps in given order:

1) Save left/top positions of all grid children before deletion. One thing to note here is that the left/top positions should be mapped not to the child position in gridview (which will change after deletion), but to the itemId in adapter which is going to be same for each child even after deletion. To do so, adapter should support [stableIds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#hasStableIds());

2) Delete grid child from adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`;

3) Right after previous step add `OnPreDrawListener` to the gridview. That is good place to initialize animations, as the layout is ready but not yet drawn to screen. Now we can access all children's coordinates after deletion. On the first `onPreDraw()` callback, remove listener and calculate `diffX` and `diffY` values of each child. And set `translationX`, `translationY` values to `diffX` and `diffY` and start animating each child to 0 translation value.

Pseudo code might look like this:

```
// Step 1
saveTopLeftPositions(gridView);

// Step 2
adapter.removeAt(deletedPosition);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

// Step 3
gridView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onPreDraw() {
        gridView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);

        int firstVisiblePos = grid.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        int childCount = grid.getChildCount();
        for (int i=0; i<childCount; i++) {
            View child = grid.getChildAt(i);

            long itemId = adapter.getItemId(i + firstVisiblePos);
            float diffX = child.getX() - getOldXPos(itemId);
            float diffY = child.getY() - getOldYPos(itemId);
            child.setTranslationX(diffX);
            child.setTranslationY(diffY);

            child.animate().translationX(0).translationY(0);
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```